# UIImageView Animation not keep last frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using This methods to animate an `UIImageView` :

```
    [imageView stopAnimating];
    imageView.animationImages = set;
    imageView.animationDuration = 0.4;
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [imageView startAnimating];
```

that set is `NSMutableArray` of the images.
my problem is that when the animation finished, the UIImageView not keep the last frame from `set` and bring back the image that was in the imageview before the animation.

how i can make the last frame to be the image of the imageview?

Comment: imageView.image = [set objectatIndex:[[set count]-1]]; place this before you start animating

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before you start animating, set the last image in the image view imageView.image = yourLastImage; and then start the animation. After the animation is complete the image view will show yourLastImage.

Comment: Just to add to this, my UIImageView was also staying highlighted after the animation, so along with setting the last frame, I had to set highlighted = NO before my animation as well.