# Keep showing the last image after an UIImageView animation

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift

I'm trying to animate a UIImageView with a series of images using `animationImages` when a button is tapped. The animation works but I want the last image to remain when the animation completes. I tried creating another UIImageView and unhiding it, but it shows up even before the animation starts.

```
@IBAction func mave(sender: AnyObject) {
    window.hidden = false
    window.animationImages = imagelist
    window.animationDuration = 1.0
    window.animationRepeatCount = 1
    window.startAnimating()
    if window.isAnimating() {
        frost.hidden = true
    } else {
        frost.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIImageView Animation not keep last frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246085/uiimageview-animation-not-keep-last-frame)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh just had to pre-load the ImageView with the final image before starting animation!

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Sorry about that @NabinKhadka. Lets say 'window' is my UIImageView.

    window.image = UIImage(named:"TheLastImageToDisplayAfterAnimationEnds")
    window.hidden = false
    window.animationImages = imagelist
    window.animationDuration = 1.0
    window.animationRepeatCount = 1
    window.startAnimating()

All done